# How to make a table for these data types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have 5 arrays I need to put into a table:

```
Year, Month, Day, number, ratio
```

The year arrays look like `[2013,2014,2015]`
month looks like `[01,02,03,04]`
day looks the same as month
number is an integer 1-4
ratio is a float 64 type

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong to put these in a table with header names. I used the `np.column_stack` of those 5 which would give me something like `[2013,01,02,1,.7584847584]` which is what I would like but in a table. I'm confused on whether I'm using the right function or if there is another type of tabular data function I need to use.

Comment: Check out pandas

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) would be perfect for what you are trying to do:

If you put your arrays in a dictionary (to specify column names), you can just use [`pandas.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to get your data into an easy to use table:

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day, 'number': number, 'ratio': ratio}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dct)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   day  month  number  ratio  year
0   11      1       1    0.5  2013
1   22      2       2    0.3  2014
2   31      3       3    0.2  2015
```

Comment: @Derek glad to help.  If this answered your question, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Arrays to be used for index
year = np.array([2013, 2014, 2015])
month = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
day = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Create random data
np.random.seed(42)
number = np.random.choice(100, 48)
ratio = np.random.sample(48)

# Construct MultiIndex from year, month, day
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([year, month, day], names=['year', 'month', 'day'])

# create dictionary of data
d = {'number': number, 'ratio': ratio}

# create DataFrame
arr = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=idx, columns=cols)
```

if you don't actually want the index, but want year, month, day as normal columns, just drop the index:

```
arr.reset_index()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: Thank you. Seems easy enough. I have data, so I won't need the random seed part, but I'll try it out. thx again